# Getting exception reading from avro table using Spark or Hive console - Failed to obtain maxLength value for varchar field from file schema: "string"

Tags: apache-spark, hive, avro, spark-avro

I have created 2 tables in Hive

```
CREATE external TABLE avro1(id INT,name VARCHAR(64),dept VARCHAR(64)) PARTITIONED BY (yoj VARCHAR(64)) STORED AS avro;

CREATE external TABLE avro2(id INT,name VARCHAR(64),dept VARCHAR(64)) PARTITIONED BY (yoj VARCHAR(64)) STORED AS avro;
```

Entered data into table avro1 from hive console:-

```
INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2015) (id,name,dept) VALUES (1,'Mohan','CS');
INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2015) (id,name,dept) VALUES (2,'Rahul','HR');
INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2016) (id,name,dept) VALUES (3,'Kuldeep','EE');
```

Now ran,a spark structured Streaming application to enter data into table avro2
Now when I am reading from hive console or using Spark,from table avro 2 
I am getting this error

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException:
>   Failed to obtain maxLength value for varchar field from file schema:
>   "string

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try following command to insert data in hiive table from spark-shell,

spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2015) (id,name,dept) VALUES (1,'Mohan','CS')");
spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2015) (id,name,dept) VALUES (2,'Rahul','HR')");
spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE avro1 PARTITION (yoj = 2016) (id,name,dept) VALUES (3,'Kuldeep','EE')");

Comment: It does not explain the problem. Use comments to clarify original question